# How to concatenate stdin and a string?

Tags: bash

How to I concatenate stdin to a string, like this?

```
echo "input" | COMMAND "string"
```

and get

```
inputstring
```

Answer (score 177, accepted):

A bit hacky, but this might be the shortest way to do what you asked in the question (use a pipe to accept `stdout` from `echo "input"` as `stdin` to another process / command:

```
echo "input" | awk '{print $1"string"}'
```

Output:

```
inputstring
```

What task are you exactly trying to accomplish? More context can get you more direction on a better solution.

**Update - responding to comment:**

@NoamRoss

The more idiomatic way of doing what you want is then:

```
echo 'http://dx.doi.org/'"$(pbpaste)"
```

The `$(...)` syntax is called [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). In short, it executes the commands enclosed in a new subshell, and substitutes the its `stdout` output to where the `$(...)` was invoked in the parent shell. So you would get, in effect:

```
echo 'http://dx.doi.org/'"rsif.2012.0125"
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works great.  The exact task I am trying to accomplish is to take a string from the clipboard (a DOI) and prepend a URL to it, so with this I do `pbpaste | awk '{print "http://dx.doi.org/"$1}'` and get `http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rsif.2012.0125`

Comment: @sampson-chen, I'd use `'{print $0"string"}'` to grab the whole thing.

Comment: It actually appends `string` to every line. Try `echo 'input'\n'another line' | awk '{print $0"string"}'`.

Comment: Using this awk command can result in problem when you have space character in your string.

Comment: In my case (macOS), this solution always appends the string to every line of the input, whether I'm using `$0` or `$1`.

Comment: This solution works also when you want to substitute the string multiple times (very useful with URLs containing version strings): `echo "3.1" | awk '{print "https://example.com/program/"$1"/program_"$1".tgz"}'`

Answer (score 77):

use `cat -` to read from stdin, and put it in `$()` to throw away the trailing newline

```
echo input | COMMAND "$(cat -)string"
```

However why don't you drop the pipe and grab the output of the left side in a command substitution:

```
COMMAND "$(echo input)string"
```

Comment: Here's a practical example: find ~/other_program/lib -name "*.jar" | tr '\n' ':' | echo "$(cat -)~/java_app/classes"

Comment: This works for me in bash, but in zsh I get "cat: -: Input/output error". Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: "COMMAND" stands for the solution and "echo input" for some more complicated process.  The "-" arg to cat is only required if there are other file args, otherwise it is the default.  So what you meant was:
    echo input | echo $(cat)string

Comment: In zsh it's `echo input | { COMMAND "$(cat -)string" }`, just wrap the command in `{ ... }`

Comment: @Madacol Thanks, I needed these curly braces for zsh. But why? What does that mean?

Comment: I like this solution, but I think you should just replace `COMMAND` with `echo`. My understanding is that the OP wrote `COMMAND` as a placeholder for a concatenation command. By replacing `COMMAND` with `echo`, we achieve the desired concatenation.

Answer (score 73):

I'm often using pipes, so this tends to be an easy way to prefix and suffix stdin:

```
echo -n "my standard in" | cat <(echo -n "prefix... ") - <(echo " ...suffix")
prefix... my standard in ...suffix
```

Comment: Thanks! That's actually very cool example of using `pipe` and `cat`

Comment: Why not just: `echo "my standard in" | echo -e "prefix\n$(cat -)\nsuffix"`? Or, the more readable version: `echo "my standard in" | printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "prefix" "$(cat -)" "suffix"`

Comment: @MiniMax Because the answer works well with streams, it will work for large stdin.

Comment: @anishpatel My version will work for large stdin too. No difference.

Comment: The `<(cat -)` part can be replaced with just `-`

Comment: Worth noting that echo adds a newline, which can be avoided with `-n`

Comment: FYI: You may have problems trying to read and write to the same file.

Comment: Here is a `sh`-compatible variation: `echo "my standard in\c" | { echo "prefix... \c"; cat -; echo " ...suffix"; }` . Note that `bash` requires `echo -n "<message>"` instead of `echo "<message>\c"`. `zsh` accepts both `-n` and `\c`. also there must be whitespace inside the `{}` characters

Comment: How do I add newlines in the prefix or suffix? If I write `\n` it just types a literal `\n`.

Answer (score 14):

There are some ways of accomplish this, i personally think the best is:

```
echo input | while read line; do echo $line string; done
```

Another can be by substituting "$" (end of line character) with "string" in a sed command:

```
echo input | sed "s/$/ string/g"
```

Why i prefer the former? Because it concatenates a string to stdin instantly, for example with the following command:

```
(echo input_one ;sleep 5; echo input_two ) | while read line; do echo $line string; done
```

you get immediatly the first output:

```
input_one string
```

and then after 5 seconds you get the other echo:

```
input_two string
```

On the other hand using "sed" first it performs all the content of the parenthesis and then it gives it to "sed", so the command

```
(echo input_one ;sleep 5; echo input_two ) | sed "s/$/ string/g"
```

will output both the lines

```
input_one string
input_two string
```

after 5 seconds.

This can be very useful in cases you are performing calls to functions which takes a long time to complete and want to be continuously updated about the output of the function.

Comment: Actually, the _sed_ option also processes every line of input instantly.

Comment: For a single line of input, the simplest solution is

    echo input | ( read v; echo ${v}string )

That's pure shell so requires no extra process like sed.

Comment: I used printf, got much more flexibility, it was easy for me.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it with sed:

```
seq 5 | sed '$a\6'
seq 5 | sed '$ s/.*/\0 6/'
```

In your example:

```
echo input | sed 's/.*/\0string/'
```

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a few years late, but you can accomplish this with the xargs -J option:

```
echo "input" | xargs -J "%" echo "%" "string"
```

And since it *is* xargs, you can do this on multiple lines of a file at once. If the file 'names' has three lines, like:

```
Adam
Bob
Charlie
```

You could do:

```
cat names | xargs -n 1 -J "%" echo "I like" "%" "because he is nice"
```

Comment: Looks cool except `-J` doesn't seem to be standard/common.  On Linux (where `xargs` is part of `GNU findutils`) I get the error: `xargs: invalid option -- 'J'`
Which system is this on?

Comment: `-J` is for the Mac version. For Linux `-I` performs the same function.

Comment: Thanks! very useful.  Please note that on Linux, this simplified version works just as well:  `cat names | xargs -I% echo "I like % because he is nice"` IOW: no need for the `-n 1` (`xargs` calls `echo` once per line of input anyway, since `-I` implies `-L1`) Also, all the separate arg quoting, seems to be redundant.

Answer (score 7):

Also works:

```
seq -w 0 100 | xargs -I {} echo "string "{}
```

Will generate strings like:

```
string 000
string 001
string 002
string 003
string 004
```

...

Comment: did you mean `echo input | xargs -I {} echo {}"string"`

Answer (score 3):

The command you posted would take the string "input" use it as COMMAND's stdin stream, which would not produce the results you are looking for unless COMMAND first printed out the contents of its stdin and then printed out its command line arguments.

It seems like what you want to do is more close to command substitution.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution

With command substitution you can have a commandline like this:

```
echo input `COMMAND "string"`
```

This will first evaluate COMMAND with "string" as input, and then expand the results of that commands execution onto a line, replacing what's between the ‘`’ characters.

Comment: and of course @NaomRoss,  unless you're required to use Bourne shell or have other crazy "portability" mandates, you'll use the modern command substitution like `echo input $(COMMAND "string")`, rather than backticks. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

cat will be my choice: `ls | cat - <(echo new line)`

Comment: sed is a line based command which does not work if upstream pipe has nothing output..

Comment: Also worth noting `<(...)` is a *bashism* (bash only)  process substitution.

Answer (score 1):

With perl

```perl
echo "input" | perl -ne 'print "prefix $_"'
```

Output:

```
prefix input
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [sd](https://github.com/chmln/sd) (basically a modern `sed`; much easier to use IMO):

```bash
# replace '$' (end of string marker) with 'Ipsum'
# the `e` flag disables multi-line matching (treats all lines as one)
$ echo "Lorem" | sd --flags e '$' 'Ipsum'
Lorem
Ipsum#no new line here
```

You might observe that `Ipsum` appears on a new line, and the output is missing a `\n`. The reason is `echo`'s output ends in a `\n`, and you didn't tell `sd` to add a new `\n`. `sd` is technically correct because it's doing exactly what you are asking it to do and nothing else.

However this may not be what you ***want***, so instead you can do this:

```bash
# replace '\n$' (new line, immediately followed by end of string) by 'Ipsum\n'
# don't forget to re-add the `\n` that you removed (if you want it)
$ echo "Lorem" | sd --flags e '\n$' 'Ipsum\n'
LoremIpsum
```

If you have a multi-line string, but you want to append to the end of each individual line:

```bash
$ ls
foo bar baz
$ ls | sd '\n' '/file\n'
bar/file
baz/file
foo/file
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat` takes a list of files and concatenates them, so with a little bit of Bash magic you can do this pretty neatly as follows:

```
$ printf "foo" | cat - <(printf "bar")
foobar
```

The `-` argument makes `cat` read from STDIN and `<(printf ...)` makes the output of the `printf` command available via a file handle (cf. [process susbtitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)). (Tested in GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu).)

In ZSH you can more conveniently write the above using the `<<<`, or *Here String*, operator that outputs the right hand side string to the STDIN of the command (cf. [Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) in the BASH Reference Manual).

```
$ printf "foo" | cat - <<<"bar"
foobar
```

(Tested in zsh 5.8.1 (aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu).)

Note that `printf` is used instead of `echo` because we would otherwise get a new line after "foo".

Comment: I'm not getting "foobar", just "bar" (using bash 5.2.15), what version are you using?

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing this out. My mistake. I ran the command in ZSH not in BASH. It works in ZSH though. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only needing to concatenate a single line of input as a prefix to the suffix `"string"`, then your `COMMAND` can be `{ read -r prefix; echo "${prefix}string"; }`. Your example then becomes:

```bash
echo "input" | { read -r prefix; echo "${prefix}string"; }
```

**Example Use/Output**

Simply paste at the command line:

```
$ echo "input" | { read -r prefix; echo "${prefix}string"; }
inputstring
```

Now technically, if you want to pass `"string"` as an argument to `COMMAND` as you show, then creating a simple function to read `stdin` and append the first argument (positional parameter) will do, e.g.

```bash
addsuffix() {
  read -r prefix
  echo "${prefix}$1"
}
```

You can either paste that at the command line for use with the current shell, or include it in your run-control file and make it available in each shell. Now your `COMMAND` will take the the suffix to append as an argument, e.g.

```
$ echo "input" | addsuffix "string"
inputstring
```

Where the function `addsuffix` matches your request for `COMMAND` precisely.

Answer (score -2):

I want to prepend my sql script with "set" statement before running it.
So I echo the "set" instruction, then pipe it to cat. Command cat takes two parameters : STDIN marked as "-" and my sql file, cat joins both of them to one output. Next I pass the result to mysql command to run it as a script.

```
echo "set @ZERO_PRODUCTS_DISPLAY='$ZERO_PRODUCTS_DISPLAY';" | cat - sql/test_parameter.sql | mysql
```

p.s. mysql login and password stored in `.my.cnf` file

Comment: This duplicates [an existing answer elsewhere on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334913/874188) which has a comment about why it doesn't solve the problem in the question.