# Passing STDIN to a subshell in zsh

Tags: zsh, stdin

I was reading the following post on Stack Overflow regarding how to merge STDIN with a string: [How to concatenate stdin and a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884108/how-to-concatenate-stdin-and-a-string)

And tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886060/5899236

```
echo input | COMMAND "$(cat -)string"
```

Which in zshell, seems to hang and crash. I'm curious what the problem is.

Comment: The SO-links you refer to, are about bash, so they don't apply to your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BTW, even in zsh, nothing "crashes". In my zsh, `cat` reports an "Input/output error" when I use your approach. A simple solution would be to do

```
COMMAND $(echo input)string
```

or, more realistically (since you probably don't try to simply do an echo, but have to feed the output of a pipe in here) soemthing like

```
COMMAND $(A | B | C)string
```

where A, B and C are your programs which produce the string to be inserted.

**UPDATE** (based on the comment by @oguzismail): An alternative way to implement this command would be to write it as

```
echo input | { COMMAND $(cat -)string }
```

Comment: For anyone interested in why this construct fails in zsh, I filed a bug report about this last year http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2019/msg00607.html

Comment: @oguzismail : Why is it supposed to work? I would expect that the stdout of the `echo` is fed into the stdin of `COMMAND`, and not stolen by the child process, which is represented here by `cat`.

Comment: A subshell is created for expanding $(cat), and cat should inherit its stdin. However I was told this issue was left unspecified in the standard. Consider including `echo input | { COMMAND "$(cat -)string"; }` workaround too.

Comment: Again something learned. I have included your workaround. I just wonder whether there is a realistic application for **not** simply providing the required stdin inside the `$(....)` construct.

Comment: Hi, yes I was writing a shell script that has to take STDIN from vim, so I can't put "A | B | C" in a subshell because I don't have access to the origin of the pipeline, vim just runs my script and offers it STDIN. Can you explain in simple terms what the { } does and why the first version doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: @ak0000 : `{ ... }` is for grouping commands, without creating a child process. As for your first version, I learned from oguzismail, that this is unspecified behaviour - see his second comment.