# Concatenate "string" and "strings sequence separated with spaces"

Tags: bash, shell

How can I concatenate stdin with spaces to a string, like this?

```sh
echo 'input1 input2 input3' | COMMAND 'inputs='
```

and get

```
inputs=input1 input2 input3
```

This question is similar to [How to concatenate stdin and a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884108/how-to-concatenate-stdin-and-a-string) , but multiple inputs are separated with spaces and the number of inputs is arbitrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could output your stuff and then output the input.

```
echo 'input1 input2 input3' | { printf 'inputs='; cat; }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the space delimited fields from the input stream, handled as distinct arguments to `COMMAND`, then use bash's `read -a` to read `$IFS` delimited fields into an array:

```sh
echo 'input1 input2 input3' | {
  read -ra inputs
  COMMAND 'inputs=' "${inputs[@]}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
concat() {
    printf '%s' "$1"
    cat
}
```

or

```
concat() {
    echo "$1$(cat)"
}
```

The second one is shorter but involves making a (possibly huge) in-memory string from the input, whilst the first doesn't, and therefore scales much better.